# How to make local notification fire only once?

Tags: swift, notifications, repeat

I'm trying to set local notification in swift firing once at a definite date, but it seems there is no such option for repeat interval . By the default it triggers every 24 hours. Is there any way to submit a notification, which fires only once, so that user didn't have to even open the app or etc?

Comment: Post your code. By default "the system fires the notification once and then discards it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval:) of your `UILocalNotification` to `0`:

> If you assign a calendar unit such as weekly (NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear) or yearly (NSCalendarUnitYear), the system reschedules the notification for delivery at the specified interval. Note that intervals of less than one minute are not supported.
>
> The default value is 0, which means that the system fires the notification once and then discards it.

Regarding your second question: no! The user has to open the app at least once! Otherwise the app does not execute any of its code. Register the notification on first launch.

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to work with the Local Notifications, but its not working. When i load my app, the notification is placed one but later it not working till i again load my app. Could You help me

Comment: @NitinAgarwal please post a question explaining in detail what your setup and problem is.